# Optimal way to check if value is unique in t-sql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there a function for a quicker way to check if a given value is unique in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?  Excluding the following:

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(45)
SET @username = 'foo'

DECLARE @checkTable INT

-- finds how many rows contain 'foo'
SET @checkTable = (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                   FROM table1 AS t
                   WHERE t.username = @username)
IF @checkTable = 0
-- Unique!
```

If you have a large table this seems like it would be expensive. I need to allow an user to change his/her existing username while remaining unique.

Thanks

Comment: Is the table indexed on `username`?

Comment: @HABO no it is not. It is indexed on id

Comment: What are you actually checking here? Surely it should be `IF @checkTable = 1` to check for uniqueness (i.e. there is one and only one existing row with that value). Or are you checking that no matching row currently exists? In which case you should enforce that with a unique constraint anyway and the supporting index will make this an efficient lookup.

Comment: First index `table1` on `username`, then change the query to use `EXISTS` as described by others. You'll find that the performance is likely not an issue. Then wrap the code in a transaction with a suitable transaction isolation level so that you don't create a race condition. Since you haven't explained what you are trying to accomplish it is difficult to provide more help. For example, a unique index on `username` would preclude duplicates. You could simply catch the error that occurs when trying to `INSERT` a new user and report that the desired username is already in use.

Comment: @HABO I need to allow an user to change his/her existing username while remaining unique. So it would have to be on a `UPDATE`. Would an unique index still work?

Comment: Yes it would. Just remember to check for Unique Constraint Violation Errors when executing the UPDATE or INSERT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This saves several characters...

```
DECLARE @username VARCHAR(45)
SET @username = 'foo'

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE username = @username)
BEGIN
    -- Unique!
END
```

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO, the easier SQL questions are always a typing race :)

Comment: sorry I was looking to see if there is a faster way to this is. I edited the question.

Comment: @Jaiesh_bhai - Your question uses `COUNT`. This uses `EXISTS` so in principle can be more efficient as it doesn't have to count them all.

Comment: @Kaf, your SQL fiddle is working correctly.  The search is case-insensitive so the "xyz" you are testing for matches the "Xyz" you put in the table.

Comment: Kaf is right. I think the `IF @checkTable = 0` in the OP made us all think they were checking for existence not uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE username = @Username)
BEGIN
     RETURN 'exists'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     RETURN 'not exists'
END;
```